# Visual Basic highlighting for Kate text editor

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting, visual-basic, kate

[kate](https://kate-editor.org/get-it/) supports syntax highlighting for so many programming languages I was surprised when I couldn't find Visual Basic on the list.

How can I get Visual Basic highlighting on kate?

I know some other text editors support this out of the box (gedit, vi), but I'm **not** interested on switching.

[Related question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80913/is-there-any-text-editor-that-will-show-code-highlighting-for-visual-basic-code/80917)

Links about brewing your own syntax highlighting module:
[One.](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/highlight.html) [Two.](https://kate-editor.org/2005/03/24/writing-a-syntax-highlighting-file/)

### EDIT (2017-01-08)

I have found this issue to be reported as a bug, but it has not been addressed by the development team. As the report is quite old, I'm assuming the only alternative is to write the syntax highlighting file myself and submitting it as a patch.
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193064

Comment: I think `Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking` (from the super user tour) includes my problem. I fail to see how it's off-topic. If it so, perhaps I can rephrase it.

Comment: I certainly hope so. I've edited the question. Hopefully for the best. Let me know if it's not the case.

Comment: Less verbose, more to the point. Danks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found by searching for **basic** word in `/home/[username]/.kde/share/apps/katepart` when I raised the same question:

- KBasic - works, but misses a lot
- PureBasic - similar
- MonoBasic - I like it!
- Ti Basic - not suitable for Visual Basic at all
- FreeBASIC - this one is good too

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to me that *MonoBasic* works best. I use the Dark Breeze theme, so I modified the syntax highlight colour in `/configure kate/Editor Component/Fonts & Colors/Highlighting Text Styles` to change the Navy Blue to Orange.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting uses a tokenizer for the language, which recognizes elements such as keywords and numbers, and classifies them. Visual Basic has a few ambiguities that require certain tokens to be recognized in different ways depending on context, i.e. it is not a [context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).

That is why useful syntax highlighting for VB is generally only offered by full IDEs that build a full model of the program that can be used to provide the context.

Most other programming languages get by with a lot less, and/or users accept that certain things are not highlighted properly, for example the names of `typedef`'d types in C are shown in the same color as variable names, because a pure tokenizer cannot distinguish between them.